# display error message soap request in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, web-services, soap, angular-http

I'm consuming a web service via SOAP. I work on my project request and get a response expected result. the problem that I have is because I want to know when the request fails.

I want that when the request is not complete either by internet problems, timeout, etc., to be displayed a warning (console.log) stating that there is no internet or "try again." I have tried many things, but only the error is displayed by default console google chrome reporting that no internet or whatever.
the console.log() is never shown the error message console appears only google chrome console.
[image]

Not to put all my code, so basically I generate a SOAP request:

```
$soap.post(url,action,params).then(function(response){
  //my code..
});
//.success or .error not works ..

//i need for example:  
/*
.error(function(response,status,headers,config) {

  console.log("problems with your connection")

});*/
```

documentation of soap in angular:
   https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap

sorry for my level of english.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (and the code), the post call returns a promise. That means you should be able to do:

```
$soap.post(url, action, params).then(
    function(response) {
        // your code
    },
    function(reason) {
        console.log("Problems with your connection");
    }
);
```

Promise documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: thank you. I've done this. but the console.log () is never shown the error message console appears only google chrome

Comment: look the picture in my question please.